# How to make multiple blocks with same dimensions but different locations in pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame

I have been trying to start a basic 2d tower defense game. I want to design the map by placing dozens of 35x35 green blocks over a brown background. How can I use a class to make multiple blocks with all having the same dimensions and color but different locations? Thanks

```
    import pygame
    pygame.init()
    white = (255,255,255)
    black = (0,0,0)
    grass = (51,204,51)
    dirt = (192,151,111)
    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Tower Defense')
    pygame.display.update()


    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        class Player(object):
            def __init__(self):
                self.rect = pygame.draw.rect((64, 54, 16, 16))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            #print(event)
        gameDisplay.fill(dirt)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,green, [600,400,35,35])
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Comment: Are you already familiar with classes and `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s? If not I'd recommend to read chapter 12 and 13 of [Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_classes&lang=de#section_12).

Comment: Alternatively you can create [`pygame.Rect`s](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) change their position and add them to a list. Also, move the class out of the while loop, otherwise it gets defined again and again every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a sprite group, which can hold as many sprites as you want. Using pygame.rect you can set each sprite to different coordinates.
Here is an example:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
white = 255,255,255
black = 0,0,0
grass = 51,204,51w
dirt = 192,151,111
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tower Defense')

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            self.image = pygame.Surface((35,35))
            self.image.fill(color)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
Players = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(#How many of them you want):
    player = Player()
    player.rect.x = i*35
    player.rect.y = i*35
    Players.add(player)

while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        #print(event)
    gameDisplay.fill(dirt)
    Players.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

What's happening here is that we've created a class called "Player", with the sprite module in pygame, then at the end we added the line:

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

which allows the x and y coordinates of the object to be edited freely

Then we made a sprite group, which can hold as many of these objects we just made as we want. Ok, all is going good. Now we used the for loop to create as many sprites as you want (you can replace the hashtag with how many of these players you need). The line:

```
player.rect.x = i*35
```

defines the x rect for the object, and since i is a variable that changes every time the for loop run, then it will be something like:

```
#first loop in the for loop:
player.rect.x = 0*35 = 0 #The x axis is 0

#second loop in the for loop
player.rect.x = 1*35 = 35 #The x axis is 35

#third loop in the for loop
player.rect.x = 2*35 = 70#The x axis is 70
```

and so on...
the same thing applies to the y axis. I couldn't quite understand what you meant by "fill the whole screen" with the objects, since that would just create an empty background. If you want to set different specific coordinates for each object, then replace the for loop with the following, replacing the hashtags with whatever the x and y coordinates are:

```
player = Player()
player.rect.x = #x coordinate
player.rect.y = #y coordinate
Players.add(player)
```

you would have to repeat the following code quite a few times, so if you wanted three different object with coordinates you specifiy, then you would have to do something like this :

```
player = Player()
player.rect.x = #x coordinate
player.rect.y = #y coordinate
Players.add(player)

player.rect.x = #x coordinate
player.rect.y = #y coordinate
Players.add(player)

player.rect.x = #x coordinate
player.rect.y = #y coordinate
Players.add(player)
```

This is quite a ramble, so to put it in a nutshell:

- you add self.rect = self.image.get_rect() to any sprite class you make, allowing it's rect to be changed
- To change it's rect you use : "player.rect.x = #x" and "player.rect.y = #y"
- If there is some kind of sequence of where you want to place these objects on the screen, you can use a for loop like the one shown in the first example above, which sets theses objects diagonally across the screen
- if there is no kind of relation as to where the objects will be set, you can simply use the code shown in the 6th code sample, repeating as many times as you want depending on how many objects you want to have

Sorry if this is too hard to understand, but i hope it helps!

P.S: make sure when you create your class you create it with pygame.sprite.Sprite, not object, as you have done in your code.